# File Input/output issue

Tags: c#, file, file-io

```
int AccNum;
FileStream myfile = new FileStream("C:\\bankin.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(myfile);
StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(myfile);
int a = Convert.ToInt32(rd.ReadLine());
AccNum = a;
a += 1;
wt.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
Console.WriteLine(rd.ReadLine());
rd.Close(); 
wt.Close();
myfile.Close();
```

I am trying to increment an integer value in the file banking.txt, but I am getting the following error:

> *Cannot access a closed file*

Comment: On which line is the error being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you're closing `rd` before `wt`?

If that is the case, I would recommend using the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement to prevent this confusion in the future:

```
int AccNum;
using (FileStream myfile = new FileStream("C:\\bankin.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) {
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(myfile)) {
        using (StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(myfile)) {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(rd.ReadLine());
            AccNum = a;
            a += 1;
            wt.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
            Console.WriteLine(rd.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to make use of the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statements

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

```
int AccNum;
using(FileStream myfile = new FileStream("C:\\bankin.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using(StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(myfile))
using (StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(myfile))
{
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(rd.ReadLine());
    AccNum = a;
    a += 1;
    wt.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
    Console.WriteLine(rd.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int AccNum;
using(FileStream myfile = new FileStream("C:\\bankin.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    using(StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(myfile))
    {
        using(StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(myfile))
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(rd.ReadLine());
            AccNum = a;
            a += 1;
            wt.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(rd.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

It's good practice to use 'using'.

Answer (score 0):

the exception is produced by the line wt.Close() because the file is already closed. the Close method on StreamReader close stream and all the underlying resources (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.close.aspx)

and I assume that you want to save changes, so use Flush to save or use Close with AutoFlush in place of Flush. here is your example with some modification

```
int AccNum;
      using (FileStream myfile = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(myfile))
        {
          using (StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(myfile))
          {             
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(rd.ReadLine());
            AccNum = a;
            a += 1;
            wt.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
            Console.WriteLine(rd.ReadLine());
            wt.Flush();                
          }
        }
      }
```